# Как исправить пропадание символа в IE11?

Tags: css

Собственно пропадает символ нижнего подчеркивания в IE11, при изменении масштаба на 75%
[image: 100%]
[image: 75%]

Comment: А параметры `height` и `line-height` для строки заданы? Если да, то какие значения имеют эти параметры?

Comment: А вообще, в подчеркнутом примере, у вас пропадают не только подчеркивания. Смотрите на урезанные ножки букв `р`, `у` и `д`. Похоже, есть какие-то проблемы с соотношением высоты оборачивающего блока и текста. Смотрите на параметры `height`, `line-height`, `font-size` и другие.

Comment: заданы для ячейки 42px высота и все